# java.lang.runtimeexception cannot serialize char datatype

Tags: android

```
    int sitesrno = Integer.parseInt(alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("SITE_SRNO"));
                                        int eqsrno = Integer.parseInt(alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("EQPSRNO"));
                                        char phototype = alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("PHOTOTYPE").charAt(0);
                                        char catsrno = alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("CATSRNO").charAt(0);
                                        int usersrno = Integer.parseInt(alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("USERSRNO"));
                                        String dtime = alPhotoMainDetail.get(i).get("ENTRYDATE");
                                        String othername = "ss";
                                        isEPHead = parsing.insertEPhotoHead(max, sitesrno, eqsrno, phototype, catsrno, usersrno, dtime, othername);



public boolean insertEPhotoHead(int RefSrNo, int SiteSrNo, int EqpSrNo, char pp, char CatSrNo, int UserSrNo, String EntryDate, String OtherName) {
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD_EPHEAD);

            request.addProperty("RefSrNo", RefSrNo);
            request.addProperty("SiteSrNo", SiteSrNo);
            request.addProperty("EqpSrNo", EqpSrNo);
            request.addProperty("PhotoType", pp);
            request.addProperty("CatSrNo", CatSrNo);
            request.addProperty("UserSrNo", UserSrNo);
            request.addProperty("EntryDate", EntryDate);
            request.addProperty("OtherName", OtherName);        

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);


            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
            md.register(envelope);

            AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_EPHEAD, envelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            boolean res = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
```

MarshalDouble.java

```
public class MarshalDouble implements Marshal {
    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name,
                           PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        return (parser.nextText()).charAt(0);
    }


    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) {
        cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "char", char.class, this);
    }


    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
        writer.text(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: E
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:629)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:613)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:582)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:566)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:623)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:547)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:192)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:74)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:58)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at com.example.CommanDatabase.Parsing.insertEPhotoHead(Parsing.java:196)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at com.example.orecs.LoginAct$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAct.java:407)
04-30 17:17:37.080: W/System.err(6562):     at com.example.orecs.LoginAct$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAct.java:1)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
04-30 17:17:37.090: W/System.err(6562):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Note: i am using this webservice and pass all values. but something wrong with 'phototype' char datatype. it shows error on that. i dont know what is the reason. please help to get out of this.

Comment: post your log cat here, its better to answer for developers...

Comment: check it. i edited logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Solution for:

i was storing Phototype as a char datatype. thats why got error. now i change to String and its work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change one line of your code

> envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

to

> envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request[0]);

To read more about AsyncTask : Developer-site

Comment: please check my code properly. i am not using this line in asynctask.

Comment: see in your code public boolean insertEPhotoHead in this method.. you have used like this envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

Comment: yes, but req[0] give me compile error. we cant use like this.